# search bar ignoring radius from css and keeping sharp corners

Tags: html, css, angular, nativescript, radius

I am building an android application using angular nativescript and i want my application to have a search bar with round corners. I wrote this code in my html:

```
<SearchBar class="search"></SearchBar>
```

And added to the css this:

```
.search{
    border-radius: 30;
}
```

But the search bar keeps its corners with no radius as seen in the picture. What should i do?

[image]

Comment: try with something like `30px` instead of `30` (You probably will need a lot less)

Comment: Tried it. Didn't help

Answer (score 2):

Assign the unit of the property value:

```
.search{
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to give this px but i tried it anyway, did nothing

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest you is to create a custom SearchBar component.

From what I read from the SearchBar docs, I dont think border-radius is supported. Mainly because it rely on Native Component, I dont think it is that customizable.

For those saying to add px or !important, I wont work with NS.

Answer (score 0):

Add the unit properly.
you can use any of the units that you like, but I would prefer you to use either px or %.

```
 .search{
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

or

```
 .search{
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

This might solve your issue.

Comment: I tried both of them. Still got the problem

Comment: try using !important after the value.